# How to show user's location in an aerial photo using latitude and longitude from the gps?

Tags: android, image, gps, location, coordinates

I'm a programmer and I'm developing an application in android.
This is my problem:
I have an aerial photo of a flat site (not a big site) and I want to see the user location in this photo.
I got the user's latitude and longitude from the gps in the android but **I don't know how to translate the latitude and longitude into an x,y coordinates in the image**.
I have all 4 corners of the map in a latitude longitude form.
Please if anyone of you know the answer this will help me !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Simply calculate how far from the edge of the zone they are, and multiply that by the size of the image.

In pseudocode:

```
x = (longitude - min_longitude) / (max_longitude - min_longitude) * image_width
y = (latitude - min_latitude) / (max_latitude - min_latitude) * image_height
```

Comment: if I have lat1, long1 / lat2, long2 / lat3, long3 / lat4, long4 corresponding to 4 corners of image, and lat0, long0 as current user location. What will be the min_longitude / max_longitude... and what will be min / max latitude?

Comment: @Umair If it's an orthogonal box, [lat1,lat2,lat3,lat4] will actually contain only two unique numbers, min_latitude will be the smaller and max_latitude will be the larger. Ditto longitudes.  If it's not orthogonal, then you'll have to do a bit more geometry to work it out.